# Alternative to Goto keyword in python

Tags: python, continue

```
def fun_name():
 for condition:
  for condition:
   if condition:
    #continue 
   else:
    pass
```

How do i jump to the outer for loop as there is no goto or label keyword in python ? 
Continue will return me to the inner for loop. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why not extract the inner loop to a function, then you can `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'break' keyword to break out of the inner loop.